# Need to use a color dialog result in a separate Windows Form

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, background-color, colordialog

Please go easy on me I am very new to coding and stuck on something that I'm sure is very simple.

Currently I have an Options form in which the user can select from the standard `colordialog.showdialog()` and the result is displayed as a sample on the form as a label

```
If(backColorDialog.Showdialog() == DialogResult.OK); 
   backColorLabel.BackColor = backColorDialog.Color; // set to label to show option selected
```

I need to take that selected color and apply it to the background color of a "game board" in another Windows form. I have already added a reference from the "game board" form to the options form.

The "Game Board" is laid over a `TableLayoutPanel` so I need to be able to change the `BackColor` of the panel

```
TableLayoutPanel1.BackColor = (colordialog result from options form)
```

Like I said I am new to this and appreciate any help you can provide

Answer (score 0):

Create a property on your configuration form:

```
Color SelectedColor { get; private set; }
```

And assign users choice to it:

```
if (backColorDialog.Showdialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    backColorLabel.BackColor = backColorDialog.Color;
    SelectedColor = backColorDialog.Color;
}
```

(note there was a mistake in your code - the `;` after `if` line)

After this, in your main form you can read it from your configuration form:

```
TableLayoutPanel1.BackColor = optionsForm.SelectedColor;
```

As noted by [justin.chmura](https://stackoverflow.com/users/671331/justin-chmura) in the comments below, you can also consider a different approach using [events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dacysss4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Your options form would raise an event when user selects a different color, and main form's event handler would apply this color instantly on the game panel. The difference is that it would update the color immediately. When it's not needed the above solution with a property is enough.

Comment: I would also add that I would think that the Options form would raise some sort of an event that the form the game board is on would handle. Inside that handler is where you would want to set the background color from the property up above.

In case you need some reference material on events: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dacysss4(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @justin.chmura You'd only really need to raise an event if you wanted to be able to change the color without closing the form, which isn't the case here.  The closing of the form is already providing an event for the caller to hook into, so all they need is the property to get the information out.

Comment: when I run this after making the changes I get an error that "the type or namespace 'selectedcolor' does not exist in namespace 'options'.

Comment: I am working in Visual Studios and Created reference thru the solutions explorer. Is there any other reference that I need to make within the code. Sorry I should have made that step clear from the start

Comment: @Servy true as well. Depends on the experience they are looking for.

Comment: @user3149642 access the `.SelectedColor` property through the instance of the form, not using the class name. If you have somewhere something like `Options optionsForm = new Options()` (or similar) then you want `optionsForm.SelectedColor`, not `Options.SelectedColor`.